# warehouse stock-demand management

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a code in python to migrate the excess stock available to the other warehouses where there is demand for each product.

I have multiple sites  which has multiple items stored(Available physical) but some items are in demand(Max) in each sites and the excess stock in other sites has to be transported to the site which has demand   .

```
data['Available physical']=data['Available physical'].replace(np.nan,0)
data['stock']=data['Available physical']-data['Max']
output=output[['Site','Item number','stock']]"
```

.My output['stock'] contains positive values which are excess in item,negative values which are in demand in items and zero which is either excess or storage.The objective is to migrate the excess item in siteA to siteB which has demand for that item

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do I migrate the available excess item in a site to another site which has demand for that item?.Kindly guide me through the code logic as I am a newbie in python